# Access the Related List Label for a Lookup relationship

Tags: apex, describesobject

I've searched high and low, and I can't seem to figure out the Apex syntax I need to use to access the Related List Label for a Lookup relationship.

It shows up in the objectTranslation XML as `relationshipLabel`, but that text doesn't appear anywhere in the Apex documentation.

I had hoped that the following syntax would work:

```
Schema.SObjectType.Custom_Object__c.Fields.Custom_Field__c.relationshipLabel
```

But no luck:

```
Expression of type Schema.DescribeFieldResult has no member named relationshiplabel
```

Is that label accessible from Apex?  I worry that it isn't, because I couldn't find it when browsing salesforce.schema in the Force.com IDE.

**Update:**

Someone has created [an Idea to expose relationshipLabel in the WSDL](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000JGzuAAG), and I would expect it to extend to Apex as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think we can get only [API Names of the relationships](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_childRelationship_methods)...

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
List<Schema.ChildRelationship> C = R.getChildRelationships(); 

List<String> prettyPrint = new List<String>{''};
for(Schema.ChildRelationship cr : C){
    prettyPrint.add(cr.getChildSobject() + '.'+ cr.getField() + ' => Account.' + cr.getRelationshipName());
}

System.debug(String.join(prettyPrint, '\n'));
```

---

```
Account.ParentId => Account.null 
AccountContactRole.AccountId => Account.AccountContactRoles 
AccountFeed.ParentId => Account.Feeds 
AccountHistory.AccountId => Account.Histories
(...)
```

Comment: just an extra edit to @eyescream solution above: cr.getChildSobject().getDescribe().getLabelPlural() will fetch you Relationship Label (Plural form) for the Related Lookup Object.

Comment: @VarunC -- good tip -- except it actually gets the plural of the child Sobject's name which may or may not be "close" to the actual relationship name.  For example, if child object is `Foo__c` with plural label `Foos` and the relationship label is `Partner Foos`, the code snippet returns only `Foos`.  I concur with eyescream that this can't be done with the Apex Schema classes

Comment: yeah that's right :-)