# Translated related list label in salesforce

Tags: translation

I overrode a related list label using translation workbench. How do I get the translated related list label in apex?

I tried with Schema.getChildRelationships(), but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `ChildRelationship.getRelationshipName()` only give the system name?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but how about something like:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describe = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
List<Schema.ChildRelationship> childRelationships = describe.getChildRelationships(); 

for(Schema.ChildRelationship cr : childRelationships){
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = cr.getField().getDescribe();

    System.debug('Label:' + dfr.getLabel();
}
```

Feel free to ignore if this lines up with what you have already tried.

From the docs for [DescribeFieldResult.getLabel()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getLabel.htm):

> Returns the text label that is displayed next to the field in the Salesforce user interface. **This label can be localized.**

I found two ideas that are roughly related to labels in general (not directly to translations):

1. [Add Apex API for Custom Labels](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000714W)
2. [need to add relationshipLabel into partner / enterprise wsdl](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000JGzuAAG)

Answer (score 2):

I think your referring to this field...

[image]

I've checked the Apex Describe document both in and around the Child Relationship classes and can find no method to provide this information. So sadly I think the answer is no.

I did however find a possible workaround to "re-calculate" the label using the related objects plural label. Its not ideal though since sometimes when you have multiple children references of the same object the platform qualifies this further. Something feasibly you might also be able to build into a solution to emulate this text.

[Access the Related List Label for a Lookup relationship](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9140/access-the-related-list-label-for-a-lookup-relationship)